# IntelliJ: Maven: Build Artifact to Jar but cant execute jar

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, build, artifact

I've set up a project with mavens standard directory structure:

App:
    --> src -->main -->java -->com -->company -->appname -->//Here the classes

I Also have a META-INF-directory under the java directory with a MANIFEST.MF:

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
 Main-Class: com.company.appname.MyMain
```

My maven pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>de.dsds.cryptoapp</groupId>
<artifactId>Crytpo</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgoodies-forms</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As you can see i import the JGoodiesLibrary as dependency for the project.

Everything normal so far.

Now i build an artifact in IntelliJ via Maven by clean --> compile --> package --> install.

The jar is created, but my library is missing.
Also when i start the jar via windows cmd with "java -jar myapp.jar" it says that my mainmanifestattribute is missing even thought it is there!

Answer (score 2):

Jar plugin can generate a manifest for you, I'd suggest to use it this way: https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#Make_The_Jar_Executable

I guess you have to add classpath into manifest file as well: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Comment: Thanks, maybe this is the reason, im gonna try it

Answer (score 1):

have you verified the libraries that are not included are added to the package in the project? you can go to Project Structure (Alt Ctrl Shift S), Artifacts in Output Layout, add the libraries you need in the final package.